# JUnit testing with threads - testing executor behaviour

Tags: java, multithreading, junit

Consider this test class, if you run the main method the process will not complete for 5 minutes, if you run the test it succeeds immediately.  Is there any recommended approach for validating `Executor` behavior?  I would expect the test to also not complete for 5 minutes.

The specific issue I encountered was that creating a `ScheduledExecutorService` through [Executors.html#newScheduledThreadPool(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newScheduledThreadPool%28int%29), scheduling a future and then cancelling that future will not terminate the underlying `Executor` as the default [RemoveOnCancelPolicy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#setRemoveOnCancelPolicy%28boolean%29) is to wait for the cancelled future to be scheduled before terminating.  I am working around this by exposing the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` being used, but I would prefer to keep this encapsulated within my implementation.

```
public class TestExecutor {

    @Test public void executorThatIsNotShutdown() {
        main(null);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final ScheduledExecutorService ex = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        ex.schedule(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            }
        }, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        ex.shutdown();
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this code after submiting/scheduling your tasks in test method:

```
executorService.shutdown();
executorService.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

So test thread will blocked until all tasks have completed execution or timeout occured

Comment: I am not interesting in waiting for the executor to terminate, I am trying to test whether or not it has.  This is very difficult to do as the JUnit runner appears to kill the Executor for me.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add below code to make your main thread to wait for some time untill your Executorsthread finishes its operation

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final ScheduledExecutorService ex = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    ex.schedule(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        }
    }, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    System.out.println(ex.toString());
   Thread.sleep('enter the time duration , so that your executor will finish its operation');
}
```

EDIT:-
you can try the alternative way.
i had same issue, i have put thread.sleep() before the actual test method

```
@Before (method)
Thread.sleep(mill secs);
```